# How to hide numbering of custom headings in MS Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, numbering

I would like to force Word to create headings like this:

```
 heading 1
  1.1 heading 2
  1.2 heading 2
  1.3 heading 2

 heading 2
  2.1 heading 2
  2.2 heading 2
  2.3 heading 2
```

Is it possible? I've already tried to hide numbering of heading 1 and it works but there's indentation and it seems I can't get rid of it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to select the heading and under the "Style" dropdown of the ribbon change the indentation.

If not, there is an option in Word for "Customized Numbered List". You can choose up to the 6th level and where the indentation starts. This is an old screenshot, but it should be around the same place you found the number formatting:

[image]

Set "number position" and "indent at" to 0.