# How to hide heading 1 numbering in ms word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

I want to hide the number in the heading 1. But it couldn't happen. I've also read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/141114/how-to-hide-numbering-of-custom-headings-in-ms-word-2007) solution but nothing works.

I want to hide the circled numbering.

[image]

Remember, it's hiding the number, not removing. Removing "destroys" the whole lists, "hiding" isn't.

I made the numbering with multilevel list, so it's linked to the next heading and figures and table numbering.

Comment: so far, i color them with white, as a poor-man-solution. any appropriate solution always welcome.